# Selenium Webdriver (Java) Bootstrap Text box input

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I have frontend code like this:
[Bootstrap Text Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6kKm.jpg)

But it's not working with this code:

```
    WebElement Field = driver.findElement(By.className("bootstrap-tagsinput"));
    Field.sendKeys("Test");
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try using `By.cssSelector("bootstrap-tagsinput input")`

Answer (score 0):

The `WebElement` which you are trying to locate is within `<input>` tag. So we have to extend our search for the `WebElement` one step deeper in the node which contains the `<input>` tag. You can try either through `xpath` or `cssSelector` as follows:

- **`xpath`**:

  ```
  WebElement Field1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootstrap-tagsinput']/input"));
  Field1.sendKeys("Test");
  ```
- **`cssSelector`**:

  ```
  WebElement Field2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bootstrap-tagsinput > input"));
  Field2.sendKeys("Test");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> First Click on the input box and after takes focus then input keyword.

Hope it will help you

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='bootstrap-tagsinput']/input")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='bootstrap-tagsinput']/input")).sendKeys("Input keyword");
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

```
WebElement Field = driver.findElement(By.className("//*[@class='bootstrap-tagsinput']/input"));
Field.click();
Field.sendKeys("Test");
```